# Looks like a reference operator but not by C++ definition

Tags: c++

I don't know if the code is wrong but I'm trying to understand what in this case a `&` operator does. I know it's a refernce operator as in this [C++ site](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) but the code I'm reviewing it is not in the format of `&xxxx`. I also want to point out that I'm don't speak C. Here is the code bit:

```
mask1 = uBRAddress & (inv_zero >> 32-size);
```

All variables are unsigned long int, except size which is int. Is this mathematical addition, or just concatination - not sure how to read it.

Comment: That's a bitwise and...

Comment: Appreciate your responses and at the same time regret having to ask since it seems such a nuisance to ask what you consider a duplicate which I haven't come accross. I get really irrated when my question gets downvoted. Am I wasting you precious time???

Answer (score 4):

It is a bitwise `AND` operator.

You can find a good tutorial about how it works [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html).

Btw, it is shared between `C` and `C++`, so it is not `C++` specific.

Comment: Thanks for you time, I know to some this is petty, but I didn't find anything relavant.

Answer (score 2):

From the site you reference, look for "Bitwise Operators" on [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/).